# Are all piecewise functions formed of finite pieces when domain restricted to an interval?

Tags: functions, real-numbers

I'm working with infinite pieces piecewise functions with real domain and co domain. 
I'm wondering if there is any function that might be definable that will not have finite pieces when domain is restricted to an interval.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "not have finite pieces".  For example, a continuous function is uniquely determined by it's values on a countable dense subset, so effectively, any continuous function can be uniquely specified "piecewise" by its values on the rationals, although these "pieces" are clearly not intervals, nor do they even cover any interval.  Thus there's a little bit of funniness with a piecewise function with infinite pieces on a bounded domain.

An example you might be interested in is the [Cantor Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), which is a continuous function that maps $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$, but is nothing more than a "countable step" step function.

Comment: Sorry, I may had phrased it wrong. The functions I'm talking about are those with continuous pieces, but not necessarily the whole function is required to be continuous. I.e. Step functions.